# @XMlId only to String but what if I would like to marshal all object structure?

Tags: xml, jaxb

I have below structure:

```
   class A {

       @XmlIDREF
       List<B> myListA = new ArrayList<B>();
       ....
   }

   class B {

    List myListB<C> = new ArrayList<C>();

     @XmlID
     private String getStringId() {
          return id;
     }
```

}

When marshaling it is only visible this **that will be result of getStringId()**. The collection myListB is not Marshaling. In other words I cannot see all data structure of class B in my XMl. Why?

Comment: Because this is exactly how `@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF` works. You probably want to use `@XmlElement` instead of `@XmlIDREF`.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I will try and let you know.